# php fgets stdin: keyboard control characters

Tags: bash, keyboard, php

When I open a terminal window (bash shell) and hit Up Arrow, the last command entered is presented.

When running a simple PHP script in the same terminal window, and the script reads from STDIN using fgets, and I hit Up Arrow, then the characters ^[[A are presented.

How to make the PHP script behave like the bash shell prompt, and present the last input?

Comment: How exactly are you invoking php in the terminal? if readline support is compiled in, it should be enabled if you start php in interactive mode (`php -a` or `php --interactive`).

Comment: --interactive was exactly what was needed. Thanks!